# What is the Difference between Installation OpenCV by Using the Pre-built Libraries & by Making Own Libraries from the Source Files?

Tags: git, opencv, github, cmake, git-bash

I need 2 know the Difference between Installation OpenCV

**1. By Using the Pre-built Libraries ?**

**2. By Making Own Libraries from the Source Files ?**

When we do first one we have to only download OpenCV new version and extract it, and configure it with Visual studio using CMake.

**But why we are going to download OpenCV libraries and others using TortoiseGit hub**(it takes many time) ? Are there any special advantage of that?

Could u please answer these questions...

Thank U

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By building the libraries yourself, you can customize the build -- for example, specify different dependencies (e.g. a local version of QT), features (e.g. CUDA) or options (e.g. architecture-specific optimizations).  If none of these things are significant to you, then installing the pre-built libraries is more convenient.

Comment: First many thanks 4 your reply. So I  have simple problem. When we install OpenCV using pre-built libraries; First we have to install CMAKE, Then install OpenCV and configure opencv with visual studio using CMAKE, and next add OpenCV library to the system path. Are this steps are correct?..So is the use of the CMAKE is configure opencv with Visual Studio?

Comment: AFAIK the whole purpose of CMAKE is to configure and build OpenCV from source.  So, if you use pre-built libraries, you do not need to use CMAKE.  Have a look here: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide -- specifically, note that step 3 (and therefore step 2) are not required for pre-built libraries.